# Ruby file not opening in text editor

Tags: ruby

Can anyone please help me on how to load my code in the editor instead of command prompt? Each time I click on my ruby file it’s open in command instead of the editor

Answer (score 1):

This will really depend on your operating system but in most case you can right click on the file and there will be a submenu named something like "Open with" which should allow you to select your editor. You could also try opening the file from your editor instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Windows or desktop Linux, but on Mac, you can CMD+click a Ruby file in your finder and a menu will pop up with an item called `Open With >`. Hover on that. If the program you're looking for isn't on the list that appears, you can click `Other` at the bottom of the menu. Then a new finder window will pop up with your Applications directory. Select your editor from the Applications directory and click the `Always Open With` checkbox at the bottom.

Alternatively, if your text editor has a command line command to open it, you can type that command followed by your Ruby filename, like

```
code ./ruby_file.rb
```

What that command would be depends on your editor and how you have it set up.